# django UserProfile and RegistrationProfile : Same model or different

Tags: python, django, django-models

So i am making a website which requires me to register a user and ask for their email and username and verify the email.After that i ask them to fill a Profile form with information such as name,age,sex,image etc. So should i go about creating seperate models for UserProfile and RegistrationProfile or make it in same model

Answer (score 0):

It would be wonderful if you create OneToOneField with User model and you can use the post_save signal on for User model to create profile instance for your user.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: I understand that but what about the model Registration Profile which contains information about whether the user has verified their email or not

Comment: You must be having your user model inherited from AbstractUser where you can do all those things.